# How do I give twisted server an ip address?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted, reactor

I am trying to write a simple client/server (where client and server are not the same machine) and cannot figure out how to give twisted an ip address.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
from twisted.protocols import basic

class FingerProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, user):
        self.transport.write(self.factory.getUser(user) + b"\r\n")
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class FingerFactory(protocol.ServerFactory):
    protocol = FingerProtocol

    def __init__(self, users):
        self.users = users

    def getUser(self, user):
        return self.users.get(user, b"No such user")

fingerEndpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, ("192.168.1.7", "tcp:1079"))
fingerEndpoint.listen((FingerFactory({ b'moshez' : b'Happy and well'})))
reactor.run()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sensors/twistedTest.003.py", line 20, in <module>
    fingerEndpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, ("192.168.1.7", "tcp:1079"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 1724, in serverFromString
    nameOrPlugin, args, kw = _parseServer(description, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 1635, in _parseServer
    args, kw = _parse(description)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 1596, in _parse
    for (type, value) in _tokenize(description):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/twisted/internet/endpoints.py", line 1570, in _tokenize
    current += n
TypeError: can't concat bytes to tuple
```

How do I give twisted/reactor an ip address?

Comment: see https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/18.9.0/api/twisted.internet.endpoints.serverFromString.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ("192.168.1.7", "tcp:1079") try b"tcp:1079:interface=192.168.1.7".

Like this:

```
fingerEndpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, b"tcp:1079:interface=192.168.1.7")
```

Also, address "192.168.1.7" should be the address of some of the network interfaces on the server's machine.

Comment: it took it without the b for bytes. Thank you!

Comment: What version of python do you use? Maybe it's 2.* ? If so, of course "b" shouldn't be used.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.3. It flat out would not take it without removing the b.  Without the b, I can see the port live and no error. "fingerEndpoint = endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, ("tcp:1079:interface=192.168.1.7"))"